# How to split words of an input by space

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-9

I have a Laravel 9 forum project and I have added this form field:

```html
    <div class="create__section">
       <label class="create__label BMehrBold" for="tags">Tags (separate each one by [space])</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control BKoodakBold" id="tags" placeholder="Enter the keywords here">
       <span id="tagshow"></span>
    </div>
```

So as you can see I have said that Each tag should be separated by *space*.

So if user enters `javascript` for example as value, it should show this at the `tagshow` section:

**`#javascript`**

Then he should be able to enter other keywords as well and separate each one by [*space*]:

**`#javascript`** **`#jquery`** ...

But I need to define when the user press [*space*] on keyboard in order to get the tag value of the input.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, `.split()` and `.map()` are your friends here:

```js
const [tags, tagshow]=["tags","tagshow"].map(id=>document.getElementById(id));
tags.addEventListener("input",_=>
tagshow.textContent=tags.value.trim().split(/ +/).map(w=>"#"+w).join(" "))
```

```html
<div class="create__section">
   <label class="create__label BMehrBold" for="tags">Tags (separate each one by [space])</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control BKoodakBold" id="tags" placeholder="Enter the keywords here">
   <span id="tagshow"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `split()`:

```js
const input = "javascript html css";

const tags = input.split(' ');
console.log(tags)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and use the Pattern `$1` to embed your match with the added prefix `#`. The regex `/([^ ]+)/g` or `/(\S+)/g` would match anything that is not a space (your tag words)

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);

el("#tags").addEventListener("input", () => {
  el("#tagshow").textContent = tags.value.replace(/([^ ]+)/g, "#$1");
});
```

```html
<label>
  Tags (separate each one by [space])
  <input type="text" id="tags" placeholder="Enter the keywords here">
</label>
<div id="tagshow"></div>
```

the nice thing about the above solution is that you can also wrap your tags into `SPAN` elements as tags *pills* pretty easily:

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);

el("#tags").addEventListener("input", () => {
  el("#tagshow").innerHTML = tags.value.replace(/(\S+)/g, `<span class="tag">#$1</span>`);
});
```

```css
#tagshow {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.tag {
  background: #eee; 
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Tags (separate each one by [space])
  <input type="text" id="tags" placeholder="Enter the keywords here">
</label>
<div id="tagshow"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```js
function splitString() {
  const inputTags = document.getElementById("tags").value;
  const tags = inputTags.toString().split(' ');
  console.log(tags);
}
```

```html
 <div class="create__section">
   <label class="create__label BMehrBold" for="tags">Tags (separate each one by [space])</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control BKoodakBold" id="tags" placeholder="Enter the keywords here">
   <span id="tagshow" style="background-color:blue; color: white; cursor:pointer;" onclick="splitString()">button</span>
 </div>
```